# Flutter - Switch with more than binary values

Tags: flutter

the [Switch class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Switch-class.html) allows flutter developers to use a well designed binary choice widget. I would like to use a Switch Button, that allows to choose between more than just two values.

An option could be a discrete slider, but I would like to the switch button design. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to "create a switch with more than two values", but, there are some options to achieve what you want:

**1. Use a Slider, RangeSlider or CupertinoSlider**

This would allow you to select between single values from a range.

[Slider, RangeSlider, and CupertinoSlider (Flutter Widget of the Week)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVEguaQWGAY)

**2. Use ToggleButtons**

I this case, you can create your buttons from a list of Widgets and also a `onPressed` to respond when user selects a button.

Also, it has a lot of parameters to customize you buttons layout.

[ToggleButtons (Flutter Widget of the Week)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVEguaQWGAY)